# using static classes in servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Servlets are not thread safe. So if I use a static function of a class, What will happen when multiple requests come at the same time. How will they deal with the static function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to synchronize it if accesses shared, mutable data.  If the data is immutable or read-only or on the stack you should be fine.

Comment: If I am using base64 in java, it has a static method encodeBase64(byte[]). If I directly access this function using the cass name will there not be a problem

Comment: I am asking this because static function is common for all objects of the class. So there will be only one copy of it.

Comment: You always need to guard shared, mutable data - static or not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of static method do you have whether it is stateless or not. If it is stateless, and not referencing anything outside from your method's scope it will be thread safe.

Comment: If I am using base64 in java, it has a static method encodeBase64(byte[]). If I directly access this function using the cass name will there not be a problem? Why?

Comment: I am asking this because static function is common for all objects of the class. So there will be only one copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using static method in servlets you need to make them thread safe by
Using only local variables when state of the variable may change
or use static variable if they dont change or use synchronize access method

and you can amke function thread safe by implementing the SingleThreadModle interface or by 'synchronize' construct.